# Zend Framework. Modular modhod. Action does not work

Tags: zend-framework, module, action

I use ready-made solution modular approach - https://github.com/osebboy/Zend-Framework-Modules

This approach does not work Action. When issued on the url - site/registration/result

Error:

```
Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (result)'
```

Anyone encountered this problem? What details please do make them work?

Comment: what is your folder structure, what is the filename, what is the class name?

Comment: folder structure - https://github.com/osebboy/Zend-Framework-Modules/tree/master/ZF_Modular/application/modules

Comment: The class is in the directory modules/registration/controller/IndexController.php. Name of action resultAction()

Comment: so I guess you have to call site/registration/index/result, because zend thinks that 'result' is the controller, while that is 'index'. To get rid of the 'index' in your URL you can set up routing

Answer (score 1):

You have to access that action via the /registration/index/result URL.  If you want to use the URL, you will have to use routers.

Comment: @RishiKalia You are right, I don't know why I didn't post it as a comment actually.  Guess I was a bit tired.  Will be more careful next time.